# Create action bar in Phonegap mobile app without using eclipse tools?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Hi am trying to create an **phonegap mobile app** with **action bar**. I don't know how to use action bar in phonegap app **without creating android application in eclispe** using eclipse they mentioned to add the files in r.java file so action bar will display in the header. Is there any other option to display action bar without using eclipse tools ? If there is any other way kindly let me know it will be very helpful to me.....

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the files with your editor of choice, Eclipse is not mandatory. If you use cordova 3 CLI to create the app then after `cordova platform add android` (and possibly `cordova prepare android`) you have a `platforms/android/` folder in your app directory. However the r.java file is auto-generated and comes with a "do not modify" comment.

I think this should be possible to solve using `cordova plugin add [an action bar plugin]`, but you should specify what have you tried and where exactly are you stuck.

Comment: I will attach the file what i have done in another file please see it let me know